# Can't access php-fpm container from apache

Tags: php, apache, docker, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have installed the latest [Nextcloud](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/) container on my Ubuntu machine.
It started successfully with the following command:

```
sudo docker run --name nextcloud --link mysql:mysql -p 9000:9000 -v /data/nextcloud:/var/www/html -d nextcloud:latest
```

The comand `sudo docker logs nextcloud` shows:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Mar 13 09:41:24.786941 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 09:41:24.787013 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

I enabled mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi on the Apache configuration of the host machine, so this is not running inside another docker container.

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/cld" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/cld" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

When opening the URL I get en error 503 Service Unavailable.
The Apache error log is showing:

```
[Mon Mar 13 11:08:35.102072 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11783:tid 140492205455104] [client 2001:a61:186:d601:f898:e50c:c181:db75:52659] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Mon Mar 13 11:08:35.102119 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11783:tid 140492205455104] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 2001:a61:186:d601:f898:e50c:c181:db75:52659] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
[Mon Mar 13 11:08:36.866618 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11783:tid 140492197062400] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 2001:a61:186:d601:f898:e50c:c181:db75:52660] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (sending empty stdin)
[Mon Mar 13 11:08:38.263875 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11783:tid 140492180276992] [client 2001:a61:186:d601:f898:e50c:c181:db75:52664] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Mon Mar 13 11:08:38.263914 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11783:tid 140492180276992] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 2001:a61:186:d601:f898:e50c:c181:db75:52664] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `nextcloud:latest`, you are getting the image using Apache, not the one using `fpm`.

Try to use `nextcloud:fpm` with your proxy setup, or using the default image without proxy (ie accessing it directly).

Comment: I tried to run the fpm image and used the proxy rules from above. The result is file not found.

    sudo docker logs nc2
    [16-Mar-2017 13:55:27] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
    [16-Mar-2017 13:55:27] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
    172.17.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:13:57:52 +0000 "GET /cloud" 404